# Social media icons not showing correctly in my footer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm a newbie in programming and I want to make a dark footer, dark navbar and some carousel content, the problem is that the social media icons and the copyright symbol in my footer, they are not shown well. They are half shown. How can I fix this ?

Here's my piece of code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">  </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font- awesome.min.css">
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
    <style>
   .carousel img {
    max-height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .footer {
        margin-top: auto;
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
        height:60px;
        background-color: black;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
            }
.fa {
    z-index: 999;
}
     </style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Dropdown
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                </ul>
 

                       </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="d-flex">
                        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
    </header>
<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators/dots -->
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="2"></button>
  </div>
  
  <!-- The slideshow/carousel -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="C:\Users\X\Desktop\TayauClinic\TayauClinic\wwwroot\images\2.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
        <p>We had such a great time in LA!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="C:\Users\X\Desktop\TayauClinic\TayauClinic\wwwroot\images\94d5de53-9c68-44d9-b307-7403941f8bec_5cfb0b35-b3c8-404a-bbed-b310f3808001_david.png" alt="Chicago" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Chicago</h3>
        <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="C:\Users\X\Desktop\TayauClinic\TayauClinic\wwwroot\images\96de3852-3519-4761-b3ce-3d711d72366e_c1c3639f-0a8a-434c-8d74-c138b3ca6f06_freya.png" alt="New York" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>New York</h3>
        <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Left and right controls/icons -->
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </button>
</div>

  <footer class=" footer   ">
<div class="container-fluid py-5 position-b-0">
     <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <h6>&copy; 2022 - . All right reserved.</h6>
                </div>

               <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <a style="color: #3b5998 ;" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></a>
                        <a  style="color: #55acee;" href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a>
            <a style="color: #ac2bac;" href="#!"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a>
                <a style="color: #dd4b39;" href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-google-plus fa-lg"></i></a>

                </div>
   </div>
 </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I get when I run my code:
[image: Screenshot of rendered html]

Comment: Looks like your footer is simply not high enough, to accommodate all the content. You limited its height to 60px, but the `py-5` class you added on the container inside the footer adds `3rem` padding top and bottom to that element ... Those `3rem` equal 48px here, and there is simply no way that two times 48px "plus x" (the height of the actual content), fit into 60px ...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the [svg bootstrap icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/)!

You click in the desired icon and look for the svg option.

The example for facebook

```
<svg style="color:white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-facebook" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M16 8.049c0-4.446-3.582-8.05-8-8.05C3.58 0-.002 3.603-.002 8.05c0 4.017 2.926 7.347 6.75 7.951v-5.625h-2.03V8.05H6.75V6.275c0-2.017 1.195-3.131 3.022-3.131.876 0 1.791.157 1.791.157v1.98h-1.009c-.993 0-1.303.621-1.303 1.258v1.51h2.218l-.354 2.326H9.25V16c3.824-.604 6.75-3.934 6.75-7.951z"/>
</svg>
```

Be careful with the colors tho! You can modify them in the style tag. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding that to your css .footer class:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

and perhaps as well remove your py-5 if that doesn't work

Comment: that's works fine , thanks

Comment: Great, glad I could help. Please, vote for the answer if it suited you so people searching for answers can benefit from it as well in the future

Answer (score 1):

The problem within this line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font- awesome.min.css">
```

you have space in filename `font- awsome.min.css`

Correct Link:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have fixed `height` for the footer.

updated code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"> </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font- awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style>
        .carousel img {
            max-height: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .footer {
margin-top: auto;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
/* height: 60px; */
     background-color: black;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
        }

        .fa {
            z-index: 999;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            </ul>


                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="d-flex">
                        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- Carousel -->
    <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">

        <!-- Indicators/dots -->
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="2"></button>
        </div>

        <!-- The slideshow/carousel -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="C:\Users\X\Desktop\TayauClinic\TayauClinic\wwwroot\images\2.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
                    <p>We had such a great time in LA!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="C:\Users\X\Desktop\TayauClinic\TayauClinic\wwwroot\images\94d5de53-9c68-44d9-b307-7403941f8bec_5cfb0b35-b3c8-404a-bbed-b310f3808001_david.png" alt="Chicago" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Chicago</h3>
                    <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="C:\Users\X\Desktop\TayauClinic\TayauClinic\wwwroot\images\96de3852-3519-4761-b3ce-3d711d72366e_c1c3639f-0a8a-434c-8d74-c138b3ca6f06_freya.png" alt="New York" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>New York</h3>
                    <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls/icons -->
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <footer class=" footer   ">
        <div class="container-fluid py-5 position-b-0">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <h6>&copy; 2022 - . All right reserved.</h6>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <a style="color: #3b5998 ;" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></a>
                    <a style="color: #55acee;" href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a>
                    <a style="color: #ac2bac;" href="#!"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a>
                    <a style="color: #dd4b39;" href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-google-plus fa-lg"></i></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```